# How to construct a model object with form data in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring

I defined a model class Task with a member reference to another model class Product. I created a form, that has some fields of Task itself (like Task name) and a dropdown list of Product objects (product object). I have no idea how to pass the form data to the controller and controller will construct a Task object with these form data. Is there a nice feature of Spring Framework will fix it?

Task.java:

```
package com.lyn.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;


import com.lyn.model.enums.Priority;
import com.lyn.model.enums.Progress;
import com.lyn.model.enums.Stage;
import com.lyn.model.enums.TaskType;


import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
/**
 * @author    Yaning Liu
 *
 * @filename  Task.java
 *
 * @date      2019-02-16
 *
 */


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="_Task")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor 
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable=false,unique=true)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String date;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Progress progress;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Stage stage;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TaskType task_type;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Priority priority;

    private int quality;


    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    private Product product;





    /**
     * @param id
     * @param name
     * @param date
     * @param progress
     * @param stage
     * @param task_type
     * @param priority
     * @param message
     * @param quality
     * @param user
     * @param product
     * @param type
     */
    public Task(long id, String name, String date, Progress progress, Stage stage, TaskType task_type,
            Priority priority, int quality, User user, Product product) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.progress = progress;
        this.stage = stage;
        this.task_type = task_type;
        this.priority = priority;

        this.quality = quality;
        this.user = user;
        this.product = product;

    }




}
```

Product.java

```
package com.lyn.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import com.lyn.model.enums.ProductType;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

/**
 * @author    Yaning Liu
 *
 * @filename  Product.java
 *
 * @date      2019-01-25
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="_Product")
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;


    private String name;


    private int quality;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ProductType product_type;

    /**
     * @param id
     * @param name
     * @param quality
     * @param product_type
     */
    public Product(long id, String name, int quality, ProductType product_type) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.quality = quality;
        this.product_type = product_type;
    }



}
```

Controller.java

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST },value="insert")
    ModelAndView insertHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,Task task) {

        if(task.getName()==null) {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("forward:insert_task.jsp");
            List<Product> products = this.productService.getProductList();
            model.addObject("products", products);


            return model;
        }
        long sessionUserid = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(request.getSession().getAttribute("userid")));
        User user = this.userService.findUser(sessionUserid);

        this.taskService.addTask(task);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("forward:insert_task.jsp");
        return model;
    }
```

insert.jsp

```
 <select name="product" form="add_task_form" class="form-control m-bot15">
                                                <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
                                                         <option value="${product}" />${product.name}</option>
                                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
```

form data:

```
name: Shiqi Zhang
date: 2028/10/20 13:00
priority: medium
quality: 1
product: com.lyn.model.Product@1e2115d9
```

Comment: Note: You're already skipping tons of what Spring is for. In your controller, use `@SessionAttribute("userid") Long userId`, or better yet, Spring Security handles _the entire process of identity management for you_. With Spring MVC, you should almost never use `HttpServletR*` as controller parameters.

Comment: @chrylis do you have ideas what kind of issues i was talking about? please i am new to spring mac

Comment: I don't offhand; among other things, I moved to Thymeleaf from JSP (a big upgrade) years ago.

Comment: why do you have id in your product and task constructor? how about removing them?